# JSP Include vs Iframe for persistent header/footer?

Tags: html, jsp, iframe

I'm sure this is a beginner question, but I just finished a course in web programming with JSP, and I noticed that our book (Murach's Java Servlets and JSP) often used jsp includes to add in the header.jsp and footer.jsp for every page. So let's say that I have a page with a header that contains 4 buttons (b1-b4) and a footer with a "contact" button. Each button would open its corresponding page (b1 opens b1.jsp, etc.) and in each jsp page the header and footer are included every time. I noticed that with this, whenever I click a button, the entire page, including the header and footer, have to be recreated, resulting in a quick flash from a blank white page to the page's content. I found this a little distracting, making the header/footer feel less 'persistent' a more just slapped onto every page.

I was wondering, what if I just had 1 index page with the header and footer and in-between I placed an iframe. Then when someone clicks a button, it would load the new page into the iframe and not have to reload the header/footer constantly. So I'm curious to see what is normal practice and if includes are the way to go, how do I get rid of that annoying flicker?

I did try with an iframe, but now the problem is that whenever I refresh the page, the iframe goes back to empty (because the index page is refreshed). Is there any way to get around this and refresh what is inside the iframe rather than the page itself?